# For debugging I would like println in functions with explicit return types

Tags: scala

I keep getting error: `type mismatch: found Uint required  Double`

When I put a `println` function in the `sqrt` method. While I appreciate its part of Scala preventing side effects, how do print values in functions so I can make sense of my programs? Is there a "clean" way to print values in a function that needs an explicit return type (like the recursive function sqrt)?

Code here:

```
object Newton {

    def threshold(guess: Double, x: Double) : Boolean = 
        if (Math.abs(guess * guess -x) < (0.01/100 * x)) true else false

    def improve(guess: Double, x: Double) : Double =
         (guess + x/guess) / 2.0

    def sqrt(guess: Double, x: Double, 
        threshold: (Double, Double) => Boolean,
        improve: (Double, Double) => Double ): Double = 
        println("current guess:", guess)
        if(threshold(guess,x)) 
            return guess
        else
            return sqrt(improve(guess, x), x, threshold, improve)

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      println("Sqrt of Two:", sqrt(1,1.0e-20,threshold, improve))
    }
}
```

Comment: the `sqrt` function implementation needs to be wrapped in `{}`, otherwise the scala compiler will stop to the `println` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing curly braces.

```
def sqrt(guess: Double, x: Double, 
         threshold: (Double, Double) => Boolean,
         improve: (Double, Double) => Double ): Double = { // Add curly braces

    println("current guess:", guess)
    if(threshold(guess,x)) 
       return guess
    else
       return sqrt(improve(guess, x), x, threshold, improve)

} // Add curly braces
```